# Angular: error on anchor scrolling with fragments

Tags: javascript, angular

So, I have this `header.component.ts` on my project, with links to all sections of the home page.

```html
        <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a [routerLink]="['/']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Home</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="portfolio" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Portfólio</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="services" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Serviços</a></li>
            <li><a [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="contact" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I've changed my `app.routing.module` so anchor scrolling is enabled:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Problem is: everytime I click on a link, instead of scrolling to the section with the related `id`, my page goes back to the top. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** I've created a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-eqc3b7?file=src/app/app.component.ts), however its getting a compiler error

Comment: Have you added id to respective sections?

Comment: Yes. All my sections have the ids that match with the url fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to the answer.
It turned out to be a problem on a script on the template I was using.
Once I removed the script (which was made to provide smooth the scrolling), my problem was solved.
Thank you @divin-irakiza and @chellappan-வ for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add ids to your responsive sections since Angular will automatically scroll to the element with the id of the given fragment.

Comment: My sections have the matching ids. [Here I have a screenshot of my html rendered page](https://imgur.com/a/3C3hP0q)